# Reading RouteValues dictionary of RedirectToRouteResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2

I am learning ASP MVC , thus new to TDD and MVC frameworks. I find an issue while writing mock TestMethod for testing a Action inside the Controller, that " RedirectToAction" in its body.

Writing the testMethod to make sure the redirected Action is correct. I read it's possible to check with RedirectToRouteResult.RouteValues, and getting value for "action" key. Even in debug (watching down to the properties) I am able to get it correct. But @ compile time the test is showing exception `Cannot apply Indexing with [] to an expression of type RedirectToRouteResult.RouteValues`.

Following is the code snippet for the reference:

```
public void TestHomeControllerContactRedirectRoute()
        {
            HomeController controller = new HomeController();
            ContactMessage message=new ContactMessage(){

                Email="abc@xyz.com",
                MessageBody="Some message here!!",
                Name="Sun"
            };

            RedirectToRouteResult resultRoute = controller.Contact(message) as RedirectToRouteResult;

            if (resultRoute != null)
            {

                Assert.AreEqual("Contact", resultRoute.RouteValues["action"]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How is this too localized? I got the same error in an MVC4 unit-testing project, and the accepted answer solved it. Perhaps adding more tags?

Comment: Second Michael Paulukonis's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potentially missing a reference to System.Web

Source: http://samritchie.net/2011/01/06/mvc-unit-testing-error/

Comment: I am LOL @ myself. Thanks a lot! Betty

Comment: Adding reference to "System.Web" IN THE UNIT-TEST PROJECT also solved my problem in MVC4.